# has_many belongs_to and has_many through,How to solve this issue pls any one can help me

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
class users < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
class memberships < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :group
end
```

Having trouble with relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the official website of rails and it will definitely be helpful to understand the associations. It has pretty nice examples to clarify the doubts. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :group
end
```

Remove the has_many :users and has_many :groups so that you will access a users groups or a groups users through the membership table...

```
User.find(1).groups
```

or...

```
Group.find(1).users
```

Also, definitely read the literature described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350230/8503822